# PHP refresh table without refresh entire page

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, refresh

I have a PHP page with one table that show any information in it. That information is refreshed every three secs.
Now I've found this solution for refresh the table:

```
<?php
echo "<div>Welcome!</div>";
echo "<div align= \"center\" id=\"infos\">";    
echo "<table border= \"1\">";
...
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready (function () {
    var updater = setTimeout (function () {
        $('div#infos').load ('index.php', 'update=true').scrollTop(lastScrollPos);
        }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

in this way the html result is correct, 
the page is correctly updated every 3 secs, but after the first update happens a strange thing:

Html result:

```
<div>Welcome!</div>
<div align= "center" id="infos">    
<div>Welcome!</div>
<div align= "center" id="infos">    
<table border= "1">
...
</table>
</div>
```

So, all that I had before the refreshed div, now I have them inside the div.
Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you're calling the same file again so you could try to do this instead,

**index.php**

```
<?php
echo "<div>Welcome!</div>";
echo "<div align= \"center\" id=\"infos\">";    
echo "<table border= \"1\">";
...
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready (function () {
    var updater = setTimeout (function () {
        $('div#infos').load ('table.php', 'update=true').scrollTop(lastScrollPos);
        }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

**table.php**

```
<?php
echo "<table border= \"1\">";
...
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: so, I need to make a copy of the table in table.php. The first time it show the content of index.php and then it show table.php. I've understand well?

Comment: Yeah,I think that might work, remember that 'table.php' has the script to fill the table up too... try it and write me back if it didn't work as you wanted.

Comment: It refresh only one time! Strange! Can be that after the first time the page is already "ready"?

Comment: use setInterval instead of setTimeout to refresh every x seconds

Answer (score 0):

seems that you load the result of index.php into div#infos

either make a php that ONLY generates the table you like to load
or consider a general HTTP refresh - which will reload the entire page